# Problema com properties Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Bom o erro acontece na segunda mensagem do arquivo de "properties" a primeira mensagem ok quando tento colocar a segunda a mensagem no arquivo acontece esse erro

> Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under
>   code 'campo.add' for locale 'pt_br'.

arquivo mensagem.properties

```
campo.obrigatorio= Este campo é Obrigatório
campo.add= Add
campo.update= Editar

@Bean
public static MessageSource messageSource() {
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setBasename("classpath:mensagem");
messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: Tente renomear o arquivo para mensagem_pt_BR.properties

Comment: Faça `messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false)`, deve funcionar. Isso é bom inclusive quando dá-se suporte a vários idiomas, manter em um padrão todas, para evitar erros :)

Comment: desculpe a demora hoje irei testar.

Comment: continua o mesmo erro No message found under code 'campo.add' for locale 'pt_br'. esse <spring:message code="campo.obrigatorio"/></span>    <spring:message code="campo.add"/> no OK